# Continue the execution after exception

Tags: java, exception, loops

I have these two Class :

```
public class TryException {
    int a=0;

    TryException(int c) {
        a = c;
    }

    public boolean operation() //just example
    {
        if(a!=10)
        {
            System.out.println(a);
            return true;
        }else{
            throw new RuntimeException("display something");
        }

    }

}
```

and the main :

```
public class Test {
    static public void main(String args[])
    {
        int val =20;
        TryException ex = new TryException(val);

        try{
            while(ex.operation()){
                ex.a = --val;
            }

        }catch(RuntimeException e)
        {
            System.out.println("try exception");
        }
    }
}
```

when i run this program, the execution is stoped just when it detects the exception. How to continue the execution of the same `while` after exception ?

Comment: move your try/catch inside the while.

Comment: Why has it down voted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the try-catch inside the loop.

```
 boolean run = true;
 while(run){
    ex.a = --val;
    try{
       run = ex.operation();
    }catch(RuntimeException e){
        System.out.println("try exception");
    }    
 }
```

You need to decide when to set `run` to `false`...

Answer (score 3):

It may help...

```
public class Test {
    static public void main(String args[])
    {
        int val =20;
        TryException ex = new TryException(val);

        boolean status = true;
        while(status){
            try{
                 status = ex.operation();
            } catch(RuntimeException e) {
                status = true; //Or whatever...
            }
            ex.a = --val;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: do you know, you have infinite loop in your example? change while(true) to while(status)

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I forgot changing it.